# what value should cache-control header have to enable ETag\Last-Modified

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache

What value should have cache-control header to enable ETag\Last-Modified? I want my resources files to be cached but never used without validation from server, i.e. browser should send If-none-match or If-modified-since header and receive 304 HTTP status code to use file from cache.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is `Cache-control: no-cache`. Browser/caching proxy will have to always validate data before serving. For success validation `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers must be present. Otherwise resource will be downloaded always fully from the server.